# Wrong indexOf in String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I want to sort a String array by second char, but index of char at position "1" is always -1 and so sort does not working. What is wrong?

```
String[] wordList = outString.toString().split(", ");

for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    int n =wordList[i].indexOf(wordList.toString().charAt(1));
}

Arrays.sort(wordList, 1,0);

for (String str : wordList) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: What is the first loop supposed to do? You want to write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and invoke `Arrays.sort(wordList, yourComparator)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `wordList.toString().charAt(1)` gives you the `toString()` representation of a `String[]`, which is probably not what you want.

```
String [] test = new String [] {"a","b","c"};
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

**Output**

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@23fc4bec
```

You should find sorting by the second index easier if you use a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and allow `Collections.sort()` to sort your wordList (after putting it into a `List` first).

Also note that your split contains a whitespace which can lead to some more confusion `split(", ");`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to write a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the String type, e.g.

```
Comparator<String> secondLetterComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
    return Character.compare(a.charAt(1), b.charAt(1));
  }
};
String[] wordList = { "apple", "orange", "banana" };
Arrays.sort(wordList, secondLetterComparator);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(wordList));
```

will output

```
[banana, apple, orange]
```

If `Character.compare(char, char)` isn't available because you aren't on Java 7 yet, use this line in the `compareTo()` instead -- it's less expressive but has the same effect:

```
return a.charAt(1) - b.charAt(1);
```

Please note that neither code guards against strings that are `null` or less than 2 characters.

Comment: As Deepak suggested, you're also almost always better of using a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) -- in this case a `List<String>` and `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)`.

Answer (score 1):

In My opinion what you are looking for is:

```
Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

You should create your own `Comparator` class:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
   public int compare(String s1,String s2)
   {
     return s1.charAt(1) - s2.charAt(1);
   }
}
```

And then call the construtor of `MyComaparator` within `Arrays.sort` as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(wordList,new MyComparator());
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap the second chars in another `String.valueOf()`, use `Character.compare(a, b)`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart: `Character.compare` is not present in `java 6` . And unfortunately I am using `java 6` right now..

Comment: Good point! For brevity I'd still suggest `return s1.charAt(1) - s2.charAt(1)` in then -- that's what `Character.compare` does :)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the index when your are looking for

```
 wordList.toString().charAt(1)
```

should be
     wordList[i].toString().charAt(1)

Comment: How does this help in sorting `wordList` by the second character of each word?